# How to parse a date string with abbreviated timezone in Swift

Tags: swift, datetime, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

I am working with Swift 3 and consuming a date string from a YQL endpoint that is in the format `Sat, 04 Mar 2017 03:40 AM GMT`. This works well with a few timezones (GMT, EST...), but when using for instance JST or CET, it fails to parse -- apparently because those are abbreviated timezone names.

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a Z"
var origin = dateFormatter.date(from: "Sat, 04 Mar 2017 03:40 AM JST") // nil
origin = dateFormatter.date(from: "Sat, 04 Mar 2017 03:40 AM GMT") // works!
```

A simple solution would be to access the date components and assign the timezone with `components.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "JST")` and create a new date object, but it simply makes the whole thing too ugly. I also tried setting the locale with `dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")` but that didn't make any difference, and the timezone identifier as `zzz` or `ZZZ` and all possible variations.
Is there something I'm overlooking or can't swift understand the abbreviated timezone in the string?